# Wysiwyg Comments is not turning off

Tags: nodes, comments

I'm new at Drupal and I am having trouble with comments in some content types.
I create a new content type and check that it'll hava comments, but I don't want the Wysiwyg editor, so I disable it, but it's still there, how can I disable it for a content type speciffic? 
NOTE: I Turn off the Wysiwyg comments in this content Type.

Comment: What version of Drupal?

Comment: Cool.  If someone else dosen't come up with a better solution, you should accept the answer (click the check mark) when the system allows you to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Drupal 6, I normally add the following to a custom module:

```
function mymodule_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  if ($form['#id'] == 'comment-form') {
    $form['comment_filter']['format'] = array(); // nuke wysiwyg from comments
  }
}
```

To be honest, I can't recall why I am using `$form['#id']` instead of `$form_id` for the conditional.

Comment: No upvotes yet on this? +1'ed, nice tip, thanks!